# Windows 11 22H2 Very Slow Access to Disk Subsystem

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-11

Running Windows 11 22H2 with three M.2 disks and two SATA drives, X670 motherboard and Ryzen 9 7900X. All of a sudden about two months ago any disk access resulting in enumerating disks (navigating to "This PC", opening Disk Management or opening any app that is accessing disks) results in very long delays of over 30 seconds when computer is unresponsive.

Things I tried:

- Removed all disks other than M.2 boot disk.
- Replaced M.2 boot disk with another M.2.
- Ran MemTest.
- Replaced motherboard.
- Reinstalled Windows from scratch with the new motherboard.
- Tried different versions of AMD Chipset Software (Currently running latest).

None of it made any difference.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: Did you check the drives? For example use Victoria for surface scan and examine SMART. Does it matter if you temporarily disable Defender or other AV? Consider a Windows update may re-enable stuff (that slows down disk access) you disabled previously.

Comment: To check if it's the Windows 11 OS or a hardware issue, boot another OS, e.g. Live Ubuntu, from a USB drive, and check disk I/O speeds there, as well as in Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yes, all the drives are SMART green but as you can see step one was to remove all the drives and keep just the boot drive which I then also replaced.